Old movie on TCM (60s or 70s) Starts with bank robbery
I have only seen the first 10 minutes of the movie. It starts with an old woman robbing a bank. The alarm goes off and people flee. The old woman goes into the bathroom. The cops are coming. A young woman comes out of the bathroom with her hands up and says to the cops that the old woman is still in there. The young woman flees. The cops go in the bathroom and see a mask and some clothing in a stall. It appears that the young woman was the robber disguised as an old woman.
That's basically all I remember. The opening credits are accompanied by drawings of hands and jewelry.

This could possibly be the movie "Penelope" from 1966.

Penelope Elcott (Natalie Wood) is the wife of wealthy banker James Elcott (Ian Bannen). Penelope decides to disguise herself as an old woman and rob her husband's bank. While the police, including Lieutenant Horatio Bixbee (Peter Falk), rush to get to the bank, Penelope escapes in a red wig and yellow suit.

Here's a link to the Wikipedia page about the movie.


Thanks! I read a summary and saw the trailer on youtube. Starting to remember more now this is definitely it. I wanted to see the rest of the film because I was curious how it ended.

It looks wacky and fun!
